# ($Proxy6) org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection@5894585b, what does it mean?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, casting, mybatis

I am trying to downcast `java.sql.Connection` to `org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection` like this:

[image: ($Proxy6) org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection@5894585b]

As you can see, Netbeans tells me `localConn` is `($Proxy6) org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection@5894585b`, and it is **not** an instance of `org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection`.

So here are my questions:

1. What does `($Proxy6) org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection@5894585b` mean?
2. How can I get `org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection` from it?

Thanks,

**Update Information:**

`localConn instanceof org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection` returns **false**.

**update**
I use Mybatis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you are using iBatis/MyBatis. If so, there is a static method on `com.ibatis.common.jdbc.SimpleDataSource` that returns the unwrapped connection:

```
public static Connection unwrapConnection(Connection conn)
```

This method will return the real connection without the proxy, and you will can do the downcast.

Comment: Thanks very much. This is the answer. By the way, you have to update to at lease 3.2.0 because of this bug: https://code.google.com/p/mybatis/issues/detail?id=591#c1

Answer (score 0):

A Proxy class is a class that wraps an existing Interface and lets you intercept calls
made to the object.

This causes a problem in that the proxy will only recognise that it is of that interface
type. Which in this case is most likely to be javax.sql.Connection.

you could try this

```
 Connection conn = localConn.createStatement().getConnection();
```

Comment: This is weired, because it does not allow me to downcast in this case. Any idea?

Comment: @DenLi Sorry the proxy wraps an interface and only recognises that and not the implementing Object. You could try creating a Statement and getting the connection attached to that.